# Does razor file support "Shift_JIS" encoding?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

The visual studio create the .cshtml file with UTF-8 encdoing. I save it ith "shift-jis" encoding by using 'Advanced save options..' in visual studio.

Now, it shows the Japanese words is displayed in garbled code.

`@Html.DisplayName("メニューを生成します。")`

[image]

Comment: I followed your operation and saved the cshtml file with "shift-jis" encoding using "advanced save options..", and indeed �j���[�����͂��B ��� �̓e�X�g�ł� This kind of garbled format, but as long as it is saved in UTF8 encoding format, it will be displayed normally. Why do you want to use your current format specifically? UTF-8 supports almost all languages in the world, so it is recommended to change the encoding.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem I'm facing now. Because of my company project's special requirement, we need to make the file save with shift-jis encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to send data from the backend to the View. It seems that there will be no garbled problem.

Controller:

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Test> test = new List<Test>()
            {
                new Test{Name="テスト",Address="テストアドレス"},
                 new Test{Name="テスト1",Address="ランダムな文字列"},
                  new Test{Name="テスト2",Address="テストコードブロック"},
            };

            ViewBag.Message = "Testメニューを生成します。";
            return View(test);
        }
```

View:

```
@model IList<WebApplication77.Models.Test>



@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>@Html.DisplayName(item.Name)</div>
    <div>@Html.DisplayName(item.Address)</div>
}

}

<div>@Html.DisplayName("Testメニューを生成します。")</div>

<div>@Html.DisplayName("これはテストです")</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Because of the special requirement in my project, will have to write some Japanese characters directly on the cshtml page

Comment: No matter what method is adopted, either change the encoding or change the transmission mode. Changing the encoding is the easiest. Why not use utf8, which may cause unexpected errors in subsequent work.